# Returning a view just prints to console

Tags: laravel

In my controller class there is this function I wrote:

```
public function showList(){

    return view('overview');

}
```

It's far from being done but I wanted to make sure that returning a view works. However, it doesn't. If I click on the button that calls this function the content of the "overview.blade.php" file gets printed to the browser console.

I do have a route inside my "web.php" file should this be necessary:

```
Route::get('/overview', function(){
    return view('overview');
});
```

What's my problem here?

Best regards

Comment: This sounds interesting. Whats the result from the HTTP request could you check in the Network tab in your browser?

Comment: Your route doesn't call your controller method. In order to call your method, your route should look like this: `Route::get('/overview', yourController@showList);` Also, make sure you don't have another route interfering with `/overview` url.
`